# How to get parent element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this part of HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Startseite</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="/pacmodule/glass">Brillengl&#228;ser</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pacmodule/completeglass">Komplettbrille</a></li>
        <li><a href="/t/Comingsoon">Sportbrillen</a></li>
        <li><a href="/PacCategoryRedirect/0">Marketing</a></li>
        <li><a href="/customer/statistics">Statistik</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I want to remove class="active" parameter and set it in li tag where I have href="/pacmodule/completeglass" atribute.

First part I successfully done with jquery:

```
$("#menu").find("ul:first").find(".active").removeClass("active");
```

But I have problems with second part. This select just a tag:

```
$('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]').parent().html();
```

And this all ul tag:

```
$('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]').parent().parent().html();
```

How can I set class="active" attribute in li tag where href="/pacmodule/completeglass"

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `html()` calls. They just return the innerHTML as a string. You probably expected that would return the `outerHTML` (for the outerHTML use something like `...parent()[0].outerHTML`)

Try this:

```
$('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
```

It will find the anchor based on the href = "/pacmodule/completeglass", then find the closest ancestor that is an `LI`, then add the class `active` to it.

`closest` is the most useful way to find an ancestor of a specific type. It is better than using `parent()` as `closest` copes with the HTML structure changing.

Note: *If you explain the overall aim, there may be better ways to do this than searching for the link href* :)

**Update**

You do not want to remove the previous selection with this as it is too specific:

```
$("#menu").find("ul:first").find(".active").removeClass("active");
```

try this instead:

```
$("#menu li.active").removeClass("active");
```

Comment: @Korl: No problem. If you do not need further info, please accept as answer/upvote. You now have enough rating :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#menu").find("ul:first").find(".active").removeClass("active");
```

This can be made more effective writing it as:

```
$("#menu").find("li.active").removeClass("active");
```

Then the DOM dont need to search for any ul, instead it goes directly to the class `.active`

Comment: Why not just `$("#menu li.active").removeClass("active");`? I already covered this. This answer does not actually answer the question asked, so should have been a comment. Cheers.

Comment: yea, didnt see your edit, but ofc. WP @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

[**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$("li").removeClass("active").find($('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]')).closest('li').addClass('active');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vbtLxdgs/)

Answer (score 0):

Easily do this (into your js document):

```
$("#menu li").removeClass("active");
$('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this :

```
$("#menu").find("ul:first").find(".active").removeClass("active");
$('a[href="/pacmodule/completeglass"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

you might wanna check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qj4ewkjo/)